# Config history not updating on Juniper ex4200

Tags: juniper-ex

I need to make some changes to my switch stack, so I backed up my config and compared it to the running config to double check. The two are wildly out of sync. Going to the config history in J-web I notice that the last time the config history was updated was in 2015. These are active switches with changes being committed often, I even made and committed changes today, but the history is not being updated.

[image]

I guess my question is, how do I get this to start saving history again without risking anything? I can't seem to find the actual, up to date running config to save as a backup. I would like to update to the latest firmware, I'm running 12.3R3 whereas the current version is 12.3R12, but I'm not willing to do so unless I can have a backup of the actual current running config.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you committing with `commit synchronized`?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration list in the WebUI should be pulled from the rollback list on the Virtual-Chassis master RE member.

Is the time correctly set on the box (eg: are you using NTP?)

Is the device you are logged into on the WebUI definitely the VC Master?

Answer (score 0):

Log into the RE and ensure that system commit synchronize; is part of the config. If not add and commit. This will ensure that all vc members have the same config pushed. Are rollbacks working as intended?